# Spring boot and AWS Secret Manager - how to feature flaged the listener to set the secrets only on prod but not on test env

Tags: spring-boot, aws-secrets-manager

I need to integrate my spring boot app with the AWS Secret manager  to retrieve the DB credentials from it. It has to work only on prod environment.
This is what I did until now

```
   <dependency>
      <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
      <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-secretsmanager</artifactId>
      <version>1.12.131</version>
    </dependency>
```

...

```
SpringApplication application = new SpringApplication(MyApplication.class);
    application.addListeners(new DatabasePropertiesListener());
    application.run(args);
```

And my listener implements the

```
ApplicationListener<ApplicationPreparedEvent>
```

Is there any way to run my method inside that listener only on specific environment ( kind of feature flag) ? I need to say that this is to early to use variables from properties files.

Answer (score 0):

### Update:

When we have to decide before context creation (.i.e. ApplicationListener is no Component/Bean), then we (just mimic profiles) set:

```bash
# env: SET MY_FLAG=foo -> System.getenv("MY_FLAG")
# system: java -jar -Dmy.flag=foo myApp.jar -> System.getProperty("my.flag")
# cmd arg:
java -jar myApp.jar aws
```

..and issue it in our (spring boot) main method like:

```
if("aws".equalsIgnoreCase(args[0])) // alternatively: System.get...
  application.addListeners(new DatabasePropertiesListener());
```

---

#### Misunderstood answer

Sure we can: With spring (boot) core features!

Assuming our `ApplicationListener` is a "spring managed bean", we annotate it with:

```java
@Component
@Profile("aws") // custom profile (name)
class MyApplicationListener implements ...
{ ... }
```

...this will not load this "bean" into our context, unless we define:

```properties
spring.profiles.acitve=aws,... # a comma separated list of profiles to activate
```

---

#### Profiles

> Spring Profiles provide a way to segregate parts of your application configuration and make it be available only in certain **environments**. Any `@Component` (Or `@Bean,@Service,@Repository`...descendants), `@Configuration` or `@ConfigurationProperties` can be marked with `@Profile` to limit when it is loaded, as shown in the ...

... above example.

An advanced application of `@Profile` annotation:

- with multiple profiles: "or"/"and" semantics
- "not" (`!`) operator

```java
@Profile("!local","aws") // (String[]: OR semantics) the annotated component/configuration/property will
// be loaded, when active profiles NOT contains "local" OR contains "aws"
// for AND semantics, we'd use (1 string): "!local & aws"
```

---

#### Activating Profile(s!)

`spring.profiles.acitve` can be set/added (like any spring property source) through several (14^^, precisely priorized) locations.

E.g. setting *environment* variable (5th lowest priority, but higher than application.properties (3rd lowest)):

```bash
SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=aws
```

Or as a *command line flag* (when starting the application, 11th lowest/3rd highest priority):

```bash
java -jar myApp.jar --spring.profiles.active=aws,...
#comma separated list
```

For (spring) tests additionally exists an `@ActiveProfiles` annotation.

##### Remarks/Note

- **Deciding for profiles, we should ensure to "make it consistently" (not raising Nullpointer/BeaninitalizationExceptions ... with dependencies!;). If needed: Creating replacement/local/test (`@Profile("!aws")`) beans.**
- Activating a profile "xyz", automatically tries to load `application-xyz.properties` (with higher priority than `application.properties` (prio 3.1 - 3.4))...also in (spring-)cloud-config.
- Not to forget: The `default` profile (activated by spring automatically, *only when no explicit profile is activated*).

---

#### Reference

For detailed documentation, please refer to:

- [Spring Boot - Externalized Configuration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.external-config)
- [Spring Boot - Profiles](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.profiles)
- [Spring Environment Abstraction chapter](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#beans-environment)
- [@Profile Javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Profile.html)
- [@ActiveProfiles Javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/context/ActiveProfiles.html)

---

Profile sample from [Configuration Javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Configuration.html):

> `@Configuration` classes may be marked with the `@Profile` annotation to indicate they should be processed only if a given profile or profiles are active:
>
> ```java
> @Profile("development")
> @Configuration
> public class EmbeddedDatabaseConfig {
>      @Bean
>      public DataSource dataSource() {
>          // instantiate, configure and return embedded DataSource
>      }
> }
> ```
>
> ```java
> @Profile("production")
> @Configuration
> public class ProductionDatabaseConfig {
>      @Bean
>      public DataSource dataSource() {
>          // instantiate, configure and return production DataSource
>      }
> }
> ```
>
> Alternatively, you may also declare profile conditions at the `@Bean` method level — for example, for alternative bean variants within the same configuration class:
>
> ```java
> @Configuration
> public class ProfileDatabaseConfig {
>
>      @Bean("dataSource")
>      @Profile("development")
>      public DataSource embeddedDatabase() { ... }
>
>      @Bean("dataSource")
>      @Profile("production")
>      public DataSource productionDatabase() { ... }
> }
> ```
>
> See the `@Profile` and `Environment` javadocs for further details.

Comment: This is to late to load the secrets. It must be done before beans creation in the context. That's why I used the listener and added it  with : application.addListeners(new DatabasePropertiesListener());

Comment: See update! :) Merry X-mas!

Comment: I have managed to find two solutions. 1. Can read active profile or 2. environment variables to set the flag. I'm accessing ot by  System.getenv